# Nine patch image in css

Tags: html, css

I have the next style for `div`:

```
.page {
    width: 90%;
    border-color: orange;
    border-style: double;
    border-width: 25px 30px 10px 20px;
    border-image: url("images/border-image.png") 25 30 10 20 repeat;
    margin: 70px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.9),
                0px 8px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
                0px 18px 23px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);;
}
```

I took it from example. And there is right all! But me it draws only frame of image and black background (`body` has black background). How can I draw middle part of images too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds/#the-border-image-slice, the middle is automatically discarded (because it's a "border" image) unless you specify the `fill` keyword.  So you want:

`border-image: url("images/border-image.png") 25 30 10 20 fill repeat;`